# conectarme a diferentes base de datos sequelize node

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, sequelize.js

tengo una duda como podria conectarme a diferentes base de datos dependiendo del usuario que se logue ej tengo una base de datos mysql en la cual estan los datos de los usuarios y en esta tambien esta el nombre de la base de datos a la cual el usuario puede acceder cuando se levanta el servidor hace esa conexion pero como hago para cuando se logue seleccionar y conectarme a la base de datos que le corresponde?? estaba intentando crear la conexion al ejecutar la ruta get,post,put ect. pasando el nombre de la base de datos por parametro funcionaba pero cuando son muchas peticiones se relantiza mucho la respuesta de la api estoy usando express, sequelize, mysql

Comment: ¿Qué caso de uso tienes para necesitar conectarte a una base de datos distinta por cada usuario?Se me ocurre que si tienes las istintas bases de datos en un mismo servidor MySQL (creadas con `CREATE DATABASE`) que en vez de abrir una conexión nueva uses `USE [base de datos]`.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.